# Javascript Sum of two values in one Input Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way to add another value into my input text. I have a **read only** input box, two radio buttons, and three checkboxes.

```
<div class="radios">
  <label>
  <input type="radio" value="non-exclusive" id="non-exclusive" name="packages"> Non-Exclusive
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="extratreats" data-target="#extratreat"> Extra-Treats
  </label>
</div>

<div id="extratreat" class="extratreat tab-pane collapse">
  <label><h2>Extra Treats</h2></label>
   <br />
  <label><input id="treats" name="treats[]" value="Sweet Corner" type="checkbox" > Sweet Corner & Choco Fountain</label>
  <label><input id="treats" name="treats[]" value="Popcorn Maker" type="checkbox" > Popcorn Maker</label>
  <label><input id="treats" name="treats[]" value="Hotdog Roller" type="checkbox" > Hotdog Roller</label>
</div>

<div id="pricing">
  <label><h2>Price</h2></label>
   <br />
  <input type="text" name="price-total" value="" autocomplete="off" readonly>
</div>
```

I've added a **javascript** to my radio button where if I click on **non-exlusive** the value of **pricing** will change to **279**. But I don't know how to add more value to if I add from **treats**. For example the price of ***Sweet Corner*** is **2,500** and they also clicked on **Non-Exlusive** which has 279 as it's default value, how do I add 2,500 to the already specified 279?

Here's the **script** I tried using:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('[name=packages]').click(function()  {
    var val = $(this).val();
     if (val == "non-exclusive") {
       $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 279');
     } else if (val == "package1") {
       $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 300');
     } else if (val == "package2") {
        $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 400');
     }
    });
 $('[id=treats').click(function()  {
      var val1 = $(this).val();
      var val = $('[name=price-total]').val();
 if (val1 == "Sweet Corner") {
       $('[name=price-total]').val(val.val+' 2500');
       } else if (val1 == "package1") {
       $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 300');
       } else if (val1 == "package2") {
        $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 400');
      }
    });
 });
</script>
```

It gives me an "undefined value" if I click one of the checkboxes instead of adding it's value to the first value.

Comment: You have many errors with your code, may you please rectify this?

Comment: What specifically gives you an "undefined value"?  In the JavaScript code you're showing, when you debug with your browser's debugging tools, where specifically is the first indication of a problem?

Comment: @David I get the "undefined value" from the  `$('[id=treats').click(function()` . The `$('[name=packages]').click(function()`  works well but if I press a checkbox it'll give me the "undefined value" error.

Comment: @EllisCristoph: Two things immediately become apparent... (1) The selector `'[id=treats'` is broken.  (2) You are re-using the same `id` value on multiple elements, which is invalid.

Comment: Provide a jsFiddle, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that you made a variable called `val` and then tried to access it with `val.val + ' 2500'` when it should have just been `val + ' 2500'`. `val.val` implies that there is a `val` object with a `val` property. Since there isn't, you got `undefined`.

You also have a syntax error with this:

```
$('[id=treats').click(function()  {
```

As it should be:

```
$('[id=treats]').click(function()  {
```

Also, I think that because of what your are testing, `switch` statements are more appropriate.

Lastly, you have multiple items with the same `id`, which isn't valid. After making them all unique, you should change your second click handler so that it accesses all the checkboxes by using the `name` attribute instead of `id`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
   $('[name=packages]').click(function()  {
     switch($(this).val()){
       case "non-exclusive":
         $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 279');
         break;
       case "package1":
         $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 300');
         break;  
       case "package2":
         $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 400');
         break;        
     }
   });
   
 $('[name="treats[]"]').click(function()  {
   // Strip out non-numeric portion:
   var val = $('[name="price-total"]').val().replace("PHP ", "");
   
   switch($(this).val()){
    case "Sweet Corner":
      // Check to see if checkbox is checked...
      if(this.checked){
        // Must convert the value to a number and then you can do math
        $('[name=price-total]').val("PHP " + (+val + 2500));  // <-- The problem was here
      } else {
        $('[name=price-total]').val("PHP 279"); 
      }
      break;
    case "package1":
      $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 300');
      break;  
    case "package2":
      $('[name=price-total]').val('PHP 400');
      break;        
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radios">
  <label>
  <input type="radio" value="non-exclusive" id="non-exclusive" name="packages"> Non-Exclusive
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="radio" name="extratreats" data-target="#extratreat"> Extra-Treats
  </label>
</div>

<div id="extratreat" class="extratreat tab-pane collapse">
  <label><h2>Extra Treats</h2></label>
   <br />
  <label><input id="treats1" name="treats[]" value="Sweet Corner" type="checkbox" > Sweet Corner & Choco Fountain</label>
  <label><input id="treats2" name="treats[]" value="Popcorn Maker" type="checkbox" > Popcorn Maker</label>
  <label><input id="treats3" name="treats[]" value="Hotdog Roller" type="checkbox" > Hotdog Roller</label>
</div>

<div id="pricing">
  <label><h2>Price</h2></label>
   <br />
  <input type="text" name="price-total" value="" autocomplete="off" readonly>
</div>
```

Comment: This is really good. is there a way for me to sum up the values? So instead of it showing PHP 279 2500, it'll show 2779?

Comment: @EllisCristoph I updated the answer to do just that.

Comment: but when you unclick, it adds again.  I still `+1` for the effort and it seems like it will get them started well. @ScottMarcus

Comment: @NappingRabbit Corrected that.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Hello, your code works but I have one question, when I try to import the values in the textbox into mysql database, it doesn't import the values of the price-total. It reads the value as "0".

Comment: @RllisCristoph That’s not this JavaScript code, that whatever server-side code you are running to do the SQL work.